# For which values of $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ is $f$ differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

(i) Let $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be given by \begin{equation}
f(x)=\begin{cases} (x-1)^3\sin(\frac1{x-1}) & x\neq1 \\ 0 & x=1\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Determine those $x_0\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $f$ is differentiable at $x_0$. Give the value of $f'(x_0)$ when it exists, and prove any assertions that you make. If $f'(x_0)$ does not exist, you must prove why.

(ii) For the function $f$ given in part (i), determine whether the statement $f'(1)=\lim_{x\rightarrow1}f'(x)$ is true or false. Justify your answer.

For i) I first set $x_0\in{\mathbb{R}-{0}}$ and then tried calculating the limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h$ but it turns out to be very dirty and I can't really find what the limit is. It seems to be infinity. Also we cannot use the L'Hopital Rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $x_0 \neq 1$ the problem is simple: at such points you can just use the usual rules of calculus to check that the derivative exists. For $x_0=1$ you need to study

$$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{f(x) - f(1)}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} \frac{(x-1)^3 \sin \left ( \frac{1}{x-1} \right ) - 0}{x-1} = \lim_{x \to 1} (x-1)^2 \sin \left ( \frac{1}{x-1} \right ).$$

Now how can you compute this last limit? If you don't see it, here's a hint: what are the behaviors of $(x-1)^2$ and $\sin \left ( \frac{1}{x-1} \right )$ separately as $x \to 1$?

From there you'll do something very similar to compute $\lim_{x \to 1} f'(x)$.

Comment: what definition did you use for the first limit? Don't you use the definition of the derivative ?

Comment: @snowman That is the definition of the derivative. You can write it as $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(1+h)-f(1)}{h}$ if you want, but they're the same.

Comment: but for when $x\neq1$, isn't x a variable? you made it 1...

Comment: Oh, I see, my apologies, my notation was sloppy. I think it was clear what was meant, but I will change it.

Comment: the limit doesn't exist for sin(1/(x-1))

Comment: the last limit is 0 but I don't get how. the (x-1)^2 is zero but the sin part is not ddefined

Comment: @snowman: since $(x-1)^2\to0$ and $\left|\sin\left(\frac1{x-1}\right)\right|\le1$, the limit of their product is $0$. If you are still not convinced, use $$-(x-1)^2\le(x-1)^2\sin\left(\frac1{x-1}\right)\le(x-1)^2$$ and the [Squeeze Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: OK. I don't get the case where $x_0\neq0$ though. What do I do because it seems the limit does not exist. as I said in my opening post

Comment: @snowman: everything other than $x_0=1$ is gotten by simply using standard chain and product rules.

Comment: so you don't use $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}h$ where $x_0\neq1$?

Comment: You *can*, but since $\frac1{x-1}$ is differentiable for $x\ne1$ and $(x-1)^3$ and $\sin(x)$ are differentiable everywhere, you can use the chain and product rules. That is, unless your instructions were to use only the definition of the derivative.

Comment: I think we do have to use the definition of derivative because we haven't been told what types of functions are differentiable yet. But I get such a long limit that I don't know how to evaluate. that's the main reason I made this thread....

Comment: @snowman Computing the derivative of that function at points other than $1$ would be quite tedious, because you would essentially have to sketch a proof of the product rule, the chain rule, the power rule, and the fact that the derivative of $\sin$ is $\cos$ in one calculation. An alternative would be to prove these four rules as separate lemmas and then apply them. Each is separately quite straightforward, although the chain rule has a minor annoying technicality.

Comment: (Cont.) Specifically, the proof of the chain rule I have seen separately proves the statements "if $g'(x_0)=0$ and $f'(g(x_0))$ exists then $(f \circ g)'(x_0) = 0$" and "if $g'(x_0) \neq 0$ and $f'(g(x_0))$ exists then $(f \circ g)'(x_0) = f'(g(x_0)) g'(x_0)$". This happens to avoid an issue of division by zero.

Comment: OK thanks. For the second part of the question (ii), I think the statement is true because the LHS is obviously zero and the RHS is going to be the limit of what we found in part (i) for when $x_0\neq0$ which turns out to be zero as well. Is this correct?